# Animate adding child views from addView() method

Tags: android, animation, childviews

I'm trying to animate adding child views to a `LinearLayout`. Just wanted to know if there is a better way to go about this or if this approach have any drawbacks.

And if this post helped don't forget to up vote :)

Here is what I did:

```
public class CardLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public CardLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initLayoutObserver();
    }

    public CardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initLayoutObserver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_in);
        animation.setStartOffset(getChildCount() * 100 + getResources().getInteger(R.integer.screen_transition_time_fade_in));
        child.startAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```